# "The reason being" — Why is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Observe the following three sentences.

> 1. I have a dog. The reason being dogs are fun.
> 2. I have a dog. The reason being is dogs are fun.
> 3. I have a dog. The reason is dogs are fun.

Even though I regularly hear sentences like 1 and 2, I do not understand why they are grammatically correct.

Comment: Related question, [What does “my point being” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80540/what-does-my-point-being-mean/87892#87892).

Comment: Only #3 is totally correct. #1 would be totally correct as a clause, not a sentence: "I have a dog, the reason being dogs are fun." In #2, "being is" is an incorrect redundancy (although commonly heard).

Comment: @JeffY - Can you explain why #1 is correct as a clause (but not as a sentence)?

Comment: Because "being" is not functioning as a (predicate) verb there. See also this answer at the link Rathony gave: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80622/150153