# Meaning of "Your Point Being?"

Tags: meaning

I commented on my friend post and the friend replied "Your Point Being?".
But I didn't understand the meaning of "Your Point Being?".
What is the meaning of "Your Point Being?".

Comment: It's a reply to many questions around here:  Your point being?  (Short for "Your point being what?", or, turned around, "What is your point?")

Comment: @HotLicks I had commented "coke is more darker than your dress". So the meaning could be "What is your point?". Am I right?

Comment: Yes. The person is asking "Why are you comparing the color of my dress to Coca-Cola, and why are you pointing out to me that my dress is darker?"

Comment: The expression has a somewhat confrontational connotation.  It's more like "What makes you think that you should be pointing out that my dress is darker?"  A conversation with more than a few iterations of the expression is not going to end well.

Comment: And, of course, using "more darker" is (understatement alert!!) not especially idiomatic.  There could have been a hint about your command of the language compared to hers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Your point being?" is an informal contraction of the odd-sounding, and possibly out-dated*, "Your point being what?", typically interjected in lieu of, "What is your point?",  with the intent of aggravating the other party.

*See this earlier question for a more thorough analysis, "[What does 'my point being' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80540/what-does-my-point-being-mean)"

It is also the title of a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0825462177) by Graham H. Twelftree.

Comment: I think instead of a contraction, the phrase is expecting you to continue the sentence (as if said second person), so that in speech it would sound like "(And) your point is/being...?", making it sound more tart than "Your point being what?". That's just usually the way I hear it.

Comment: @Tyress, you are right, I probably selected the wrong word. The sentence is a condensed, reconstruction form of the question, "What is your point?", omitting the pronoun "what"; the effect of which you have accurately stated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally asked the friend.
After the reply, I found that the friend is trying to know about the connection of color of coke and the dress.
So the friend is little bit confusion and want to know more.
So the meaning of "your point being?" is "what is your point or what is the connection between the thing you are saying?".